# По миру или помиру?

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия, слитно-раздельно

Если отправился в путешествие, или если обнищал предельно.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Пускать (пустить) **по́  миру** (с сумой)](https://phraseology.academic.ru/10215/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83) *кого*.  Разг. Экспрес. Доводить до нищеты; разорять.
   ***Пойти*** (ходить, идти и т. п.) ***по́ миру*** — обеднев, начать нищенствовать, побираться.

*Что ж, справедливо то, что, по нагорной проповеди, надо раздавать своё имение чужим, а семью **пустить по́ миру*** (Л. Н. Толстой); *Сделка была совершена, и безымянные тени наши **пущены по́ миру*** (В. В. Набоков); *Кто ему враг, того он мало что **пустит по́ миру**, но ещё и руки будет потирать от удовольствия* (С. Моэм); *А деньжата из нашего дома убывали со скоростью света. И я понял, что скоро мы с отцом **пойдём по́ миру*** (Е. И. Сазанович).

2. Путешествовать, странствовать, кочевать, колесить, перемещаться, ездить, разъезжать, летать — **по ми́ру.**

*Федор Конюхов отправился в путешествие **по ми́ру** на воздушном шаре.*

*Потом ещё три года разъезжал **по ми́ру**, довольствуясь только самым необходимым: одной парой обуви и небольшим рюкзаком, в котором был сложен комплект одежды* (Е. Е. Сухов).

**По миру** — всегда раздельно; различие только в значении и ударении.

Answer (score 0):

Раздѣльно.

«Пойти по міру»

> - Жив быть не хочу, а разорю их вдребезг! Нищими по миру пойдут, три года будут милостыней жить.

М. Горький, Мои университеты.

Answer (score 0):

А. П. Чехов, Письма. 11 том. Издание Художественная литература. 1956 г. Стр. 140. «...обратно в Москву, чтобы не пойти помиру».

Comment: Здравствуйте, _borishalizov._ Вы уверены, что процитировали правильно? _Езжу теперь в III классе, и как только у меня останется в кармане 20 р., тотчас же попру обратно в Москву, чтобы не **пойти по миру**._ http://chehov-lit.ru/chehov/letters/1887-1888/letter-268.htm